# Definition of complex derivative for a function of a single complex variable with values in a matrix of complex functions

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, derivatives

I preface this question by saying that my complex-analysis is borderline nonexistent. In the Wikipedia page for a [Holomorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), the derivative of a complex-valued function $f$ of a single variable at a point $z_0$ in it's domain is defined as the limit
$$f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}.$$
How would you adapt this definition of the complex derivative if instead you had a mapping $g$ of a single complex-variable of the form
$$\begin{equation}
g:z\mapsto g(z)=
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{11}(z)&f_{12}(z)\\
f_{21}(z)&f_{22}(z)
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}$$
where each $f_{ij}$, for $i,j\in\left\{1,2\right\}$, is a complex-valued function $f$ of a single variable? Is it as simple as slightly amending the original quotient in the following manner so as to not be 'dividing a matrix'

$$
\begin{align}
g'(z_0)&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{{z-z_0}}\left(g(z)-g(z_0)\right)\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{{z-z_0}}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{11}(z)-f_{11}(z_0)&f_{12}(z)-f_{12}(z_0)\\
f_{21}(z)-f_{21}(z_0)&f_{22}(z)-f_{22}(z_0)
\end{pmatrix}, 
\end{align}$$
or does it require another perspective entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your definition is fine.

One generalization which captures many different notions of differentiability is the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).

In your case, you have $g: \mathbb{C} \to M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{C})$.  It doesn't actually matter which norm you use in the finite dimensional case.  You can check that your definition agrees with the definition from wikipedia choosing whichever norm you like best for the codomain.